# Trying to use nested maps in JSX cant get it to work

Tags: reactjs, loops

I am trying to use nested map loops to loop through an array then loop through another array associated with the higher array.

What am I doing wrong? Thanks in advance..

```
                    <Workbook filename="example.xlsx" element={<button className="btn btn-lg btn-primary">Try me!</button>}>
                { dataArray.map((data) => 
                  <Workbook.Sheet data={data.rows} name={data.name}>
                    {
                      data.columns.map((col) =>
                          <Workbook.Column label={col.text} value={col.dataField} />
                      )
                    }
                  </Workbook.Sheet>
                }
                </Workbook>
              </Dropdown.Item>
```

Comment: try with `<div/>` first ... use `key` in loops

Comment: do you get any errors?